# Best practice with Broadcast Receiver and Service combination

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

In my application I am using broadcast receiver to detect proximity alert changes recorded and registered before. But when proximity alert received on broadcast receiver I need to do what my app does. I am creating service when application first opened up and I am thinking using that service to do that job when broadcast received calling from BroadcastReceiver cause even if application killed by OS I want my app to be functional. What is the best practice for this kind of situation, am I on the right track ?

Edit : And I am also using

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</intent-filter>
```

BOOT_COMPLETED intent filter to reregister my BroadcastReceiver if user bootup device.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes you are on right track**

On BootCompleted you can start a 
service in onReceive() method of broadcastReceiver class.As when
andoid phone will start it will broadcast intent.
Remember Never Unregister this broadcast in complete application

Comment: Now, broadcastreciever will be registered on bootup but all my proximity alerts will be gone so probably it wont recieve anything cause I registerd alerts with my application but on bootup application will not be present ( I add all my proximity alerts on application start) so my proximityAlerts. My application must be reopened to reregister proximity alerts or I should reregister them on another place ?

Comment: onBootup you can start an application also

Comment: yeah than user will face with the ui of the application I think thats not a thing they want. I wanna establish this in background

Comment: you can start a service in onReceive() of broadcast so you need not interact with UI

Answer (score 0):

I know that the thread is old but:

1. Do not forget the permission for boot complete android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED if you use the BOOT_COMPLETED filter intent.
2. It depends on the logic of your app BUT if your logic requires starting a permanent background service that does some logic at the background (listening for sensor data etc...) you can start the service and other needed initialisations in your Application class. This will promise you that once your onReceive of the BroadcastReceiver is called (even after boot complete) all your initialisations will be ready as your Application onCreate was already called.